# How to remove Multiple Items from RadComboBox

Tags: c#, radcombobox

I have a RadComboBox like below

```
 <radC:RadComboBox ID="lstMaterial" runat="server" Width="100px"  Height="100px" DropDownWidth="100px" />
```

in aspx.cs page based on condition need to add and remove multiple items from the above RadComboBox control like below.

```
if(isTrue)
{
    //Remove
            List<string> strRemoveList = new List<string>();
                    strRemoveList.Add(lstMaterial.FindItemByText("Wood1").ToString());
                    strRemoveList.Add(lstMaterial.FindItemByText("Seam").ToString());
                    strRemoveList.Add(lstMaterial.FindItemByText("wood2").ToString());

                   // lstMaterial.Items.Remove(strConstructionStyleRemoveList);
           //foreach(RadComboBoxItem rcbi in lstConstructionStyle.Items)
                   // {
                   //     rcbi.Remove(strRemoveList);
                    // }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the error you are running into is due to removing items from the source of a foreach loop. Try looping the strRemoveList instead, and then remove from rcbi within that loop.

Example:

```
foreach(string itemToRemove in strRemoveList)
{
    rcbi.Remove(itemToRemove);
}
```